# How to solve the error : AttributeError: module 'pyglfw' has no attribute 'pyglfwInit'

Tags: python, ubuntu, opengl, glfw

I want to make a openGL project using python. And the below code is creating the window to display the graphic.

```
import os

import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *


class renderwindow():
    '''GLFW Renderting window class'''

    def __init__(self):

        #save current working directory
        cwd = os.getcwd()

        #initialize glfw
        glfw.glfwInit()

        #restore cws
        os.chdir(cwd)

        #version hints
        glfw.glfwWindowHint()

        glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
        glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
        glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE)
        glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,
                            glfw.GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

        # make a window
        self.width, self.height = 640, 480
        self.aspect = self.width / float(self.height)
        self.win = glfw.glfwCreateWindow(self.width, self.height,
                                         b'simpleglfw')

        # make the context current
        glfw.glfwMakeContextCurrent(self.win)

    def main(self):
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
```

When I run the code, it report error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/192/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1438, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/192/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/surface/Final-Year-Project/FYP/Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    class main():
  File "/home/surface/Final-Year-Project/FYP/Main.py", line 29, in main
    rw = renderwindow()
  File "/home/surface/Final-Year-Project/FYP/Open_GL_project1/RenderWIndow.py", line 16, in __init__
    glfw.glfwInit()
AttributeError: module 'glfw' has no attribute 'glfwInit'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I search the solution in the internet and some people say problem caused by old version of GLFW . The pycharm mismatch the GLFW. I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the method is not `glfwInit`, it is `init`. This applies to the other methods, too. (`window_hint`, `create_window`, `make_context_current`):

```py
import os

import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *

class renderwindow():
    '''GLFW Renderting window class'''

    def __init__(self):

        #save current working directory
        cwd = os.getcwd()

        #initialize glfw
        glfw.init()

        #restore cws
        os.chdir(cwd)

        #version hints
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE,
                            glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

        # make a window
        self.width, self.height = 640, 480
        self.aspect = self.width / float(self.height)
        self.win = glfw.create_window(self.width, self.height,
                                         'simpleglfw', None, None)

        # make the context current
        glfw.make_context_current(self.win)

    def main(self):
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
```

---

Alternatively `import glfw.GLFW  as glfw`:

```py
import os

#import glfw
import glfw.GLFW as glfw

from OpenGL.GL import *

class renderwindow():
    '''GLFW Renderting window class'''

    def __init__(self):

        #save current working directory
        cwd = os.getcwd()

        #initialize glfw
        glfw.glfwInit()

        #restore cws
        os.chdir(cwd)

        #version hints
        glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
        glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
        glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE)
        glfw.glfwWindowHint(glfw.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,
                            glfw.GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

        # make a window
        self.width, self.height = 640, 480
        self.aspect = self.width / float(self.height)
        self.win = glfw.glfwCreateWindow(self.width, self.height,
                                         'simpleglfw', None, None)

        # make the context current
        glfw.glfwMakeContextCurrent(self.win)

    def main(self):
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)

wnd = renderwindow()
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me where can I find the API document about OpenGL by python? I can just find the document about c++ in glfw.org/docs/.

Comment: @LangTuo The pyopengl API can be found at [PyOpenGL Documentation](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/index.html), respectively [GL Reference](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/index.html#GL)

Comment: ＠Rabbid76 Thanks a lot!